# How can I change numerical abbreviations in charts in Superset

Tags: charts, visualization, config, open-source, apache-superset

How can I change numerical abbreviations in charts, for example from 5k to Polish 5tyś? Is it possible to do this?

I was looking for a config file to change that but with no results. Is this possible and where can I change this?

Answer (score -1):

You will probably find the answer in this documentation [D3 formating](https://docs.preset.io/docs/axis-formatting) under Axis Formatting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).